# Android why does my checkDB keep giving false?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a button that switches to one of 2 activities based on whether a database exists. I've made a databasecheckhelper but for some reason it keeps giving out false, even though the database exists.

code on clicking the button:

```
public void open_my_training(View view) {

    Intent intent;

    boolean databaseExists = checkDatabase.checkDB(this);
    if(databaseExists){
        intent = new Intent(this, a.class);
    }else{
        intent = new Intent(this, b.class);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

the helper

```
public class checkDatabase {

    public static boolean checkDB(Context context) {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath("database.db");
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

edit:

since the code seems to be fine i'll add my code for creating the database:

```
public void save_training(View view) {

    CheckBox box1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box1);
    CheckBox box2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box2);


    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String spinner1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

    createDatabase();
    addTraining(box1.isChecked(), box2.isChecked(), spinner1);
}


private void createDatabase() {
    try {

        trainingDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("database.sqlite", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        trainingDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1" + "(id integer primary key," +
                "box1 boolean, box2 boolean, + "spinner1 VARCHAR);");

}

private void addTraining(boolean box1Checked, boolean box2Checked, String spinner1) {

    trainingDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO table1 (box1, box2, spinner1) VALUES ('"+ box1Checked + "', '" +
            box2Checked + "', '" + spinner1 + "');");
}
```

Comment: make sure your db file is `database.db` or `database.sqlite`?

Comment: doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: ru able use created db befor use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath("database.sqlite");`

instead of

`File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath("database.db");`

Comment: i've tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: you try with Emulator or device?

Comment: I use a device to run the app. I'm still a noob when it comes to using the debugger so I don't really know where the problem is.

Comment: got it to work, i just had to update every call in my app too .sqlite Thanks

Comment: happy to hear @Mischa always wlc